# EAR Content not Bounded Exception

Tags: jboss, ejb, ejb-3.0, jndi, web-deployment

I am using JBoss AS 5.0.1 and and I am getting the following error when i Try to Invoke my Servlet.

```
17:11:48,060 ERROR [STDERR] javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: EJBSvcApp not bound
```

I have Created an EAR by the Above name to which I have Added my EJB and Web Project.
I have also Included EJBClient in deployment assembly of my Web App. Below is the JBoss Log Trace. I also See a warning in the Log Which I am not sure what it is.

```
17:09:27,962 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@457214762{vfszip:/C:/jboss-     5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/EJBSvcApp.ear/EJBSvcEJB.jar/}
17:09:27,963 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@457214762{vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/EJBSvcApp.ear/EJBSvcEJB.jar/}
17:09:27,963 INFO  [Ejb3DependenciesDeployer] Encountered deployment AbstractVFSDeploymentContext@457214762{vfszip:/C:/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/EJBSvcApp.ear/EJBSvcEJB.jar/}
7:09:27,986 WARN  [Ejb3AnnotationHandler] JBMETA-4: did not find any bean meta data for annotation bean OrderBean, will create some
17:09:33,622 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Created KernelDeployment for: EJBSvcEJB.jar
17:09:33,626 INFO  [JBossASKernel] installing bean: jboss.j2ee:ear=EJBSvcApp.ear,jar=EJBSvcEJB.jar,name=OrderBean,service=EJB3
17:09:33,626 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   with dependencies:
17:09:33,626 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and demands:
17:09:33,627 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  jboss.ejb:service=EJBTimerService
17:09:33,627 INFO  [JBossASKernel]   and supplies:
17:09:33,627 INFO  [JBossASKernel]  Class:com.webpage.ejb.Order
17:09:33,627 INFO  [JBossASKernel] Added bean(jboss.j2ee:ear=EJBSvcApp.ear,jar=EJBSvcEJB.jar,name=OrderBean,service=EJB3) to KernelDeployment of: EJBSvcEJB.jar
17:09:33,776 INFO  [SessionSpecContainer] Starting jboss.j2ee:ear=EJBSvcApp.ear,jar=EJBSvcEJB.jar,name=OrderBean,service=EJB3
17:09:33,786 INFO  [EJBContainer] STARTED EJB: com.webpage.ejb.OrderBean ejbName: OrderBean
17:09:33,791 INFO  [JndiSessionRegistrarBase] Binding the following Entries in Global JNDI:


17:09:33,850 WARN  [WebServiceDeployerEJB] Ingore ejb deployment with null classname: org.jboss.metadata.ejb.jboss.JBossSessionBeanMetaData@6012d7fe{OrderBean}
17:09:33,928 INFO  [TomcatDeployment] deploy, ctxPath=/EJBSvcWeb
```

I have Created An EJB INterface

```
@Remote()
public interface Order {...
```

and Bean

```
@Stateless(name = "OrderBean")
public class OrderBean implements Order { ...
```

I am making a lookup in My Servlet as below

```
Order o = (Order)(new InitialContext()).lookup("EJBSvcApp/OrderBean/remote");
```

Comment: I think you are trying look up the bean using a wrong name ("EJBSvcApp/OrderBean/remote"), try to search in the log the ejb name used when jboss deploys it, probably is just ("OrderBean")

Comment: Thanks for Reply, but I don't think Its the name.I tested using your comments but It is giving em an exception saying that OrderBean not found. Which was not the Exception in previous case. If you can see the Second Last and the Third Last line in the Logs I have provided above I beleive it has not added it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this part:

```
 [Ejb3AnnotationHandler] JBMETA-4: did not find any bean meta data for annotation bean OrderBean, will create some
```

[It seems to be that the problem](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBMETA-208?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel) is a Jboss AS 5.1.0 GA's bug.

If I understood the post correctly, the problem is originated because you have an empty META-INF/ejb-jar.xml file.

I would try to:

a) delete the file. (I think this will be enough).

b) or try to fill it with the next :

```
<ejb-jar version="3.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
</ejb-jar>
```